# Fetch data from external database to WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress, I have an old website containing a simple database to my diner's menu, I am switching my website to WordPress and I need to use my old database, is their anyway I can use both databases? The one already in WordPress and my own database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this or refer to this forum: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-databases-16/

```
    function seconddb() {
             global $seconddb;
             $seconddb = new 
             wpdb('Username','password','database name','localhost');
    }
    add_action('init','seconddb');
```

Comment: can u please lead me to to the file where i can add this function?

Comment: You should have a functions.php file in your themes folder: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/